# MATLAB: Matrix to Vector row-wise

Tags: matlab, vector, matrix, row, reshape

How to turn a matrix into a vector row-wise efficiently.
Example:

```
>> a = [1 2; 3 4]

a =

     1     2
     3     4
```

the `(:)` notation gives me:

```
>> a(:)

ans =

     1
     3
     2
     4
```

but I want to get the result as this:

```
>> b = a'; b(:)

ans =

     1
     2
     3
     4
```

The transposition and the additional var-assignment makes it much slower.
I could do it without the assignment via reshape like this:

```
>> reshape(a',4,1)

ans =

     1
     2
     3
     4
```

which is a very small bit faster then the previous one, see the bench:

```
runs = 1000;
num = 1000;
A = rand(num);

times = zeros(runs, 2);
for i = 1:runs
    tic
    x = A';
    x = x(:);
    t1 = toc;
    x = reshape(A',size(A,1)*size(A,2),1);
    t2 = toc-t1;
    times(i,:) = [t1 t2];    
end
format shortG
mt = mean(times)

mt =

    0.0037877    0.0037699
```

If I'm leaving away the transposition it would be very very much faster and the `(:)` syntax would be >100% faster:

```
runs = 100;
num = 5000;
A = rand(num);

times = zeros(runs, 2);
for i = 1:runs
    tic
    x = A(:);
    t1 = toc;
    x = reshape(A,size(A,1)*size(A,2),1);
    t2 = toc-t1;
    times(i,:) = [t1 t2];    
end
format shortG
mt = mean(times)

mt =

    3.307e-07   8.8382e-07
```

that's why I'm asking if there's such a nice syntax like `(:)` but to get it row-wise to a vector!?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think about how the elements are organized in memory. Their "natural" order is column wise. Thus `A(:)` simply changes the header of the matrix but does **not** need to change enything in the memory storing the elements themselfs. However, when you transpose `A`, you need to re-arrange the elements in memory (copying and swapping) and this takes time.

Comment: yeah I thought of something like this too, as I knew that MATLAB, like fortran, holds the data in memory in major column format http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order#Column-major_order, but still thought it would somehow be possible to convert to a vector faster

Comment: @bjoern I suppose there's no way around the need to swap elements in memory.